# How to step into my code (F11) without getting into the external libraries in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How to step into my code (<kbd>F11</kbd>) without getting into the external libraries  like xstring, xutility?

Comment: Use F10 to skip over functions you don't want to see.

Comment: And shft-f11 to step out.

Comment: Is "just my code" enabled in the debugger settings? See e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/10/25/understanding-just-my-code/. Don't know if that's sufficient for you.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 (2015 might have same setting): Toots > Options > Debugging > General > [X] Enable Just My Code.

Comment: "Just my code" doesn't work for headers (at least it never has for me)

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>F10</kbd>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: F10 won't give me the full proccess, I can't see what my data types equel to

Comment: @MaximMaxi I have no idea what you mean by that. F10 is the correct key.

Comment: @MaximMaxi F10 is "step over", which shows the exact same information when debugging as using F11 "step into". The only difference is that it skips over a function …

Comment: @MaximMaxi Multiple types of stepping exist for multiple cases. F11 -> step into, Shift-F11 -> step out, F10 -> step over. Use F10 on lines that you don't care about seeing the internal code, and F11 where you do want to follow the call stack down.

Answer (score 0):

Shift F11 while debbuging helped me.